# Do matching (left/right) lights often burn out within a short time period of each other? If so, why?

Tags: headlight, kia, rio

A couple of weeks ago, the right headlight in my car burnt out, so I went to the garage and had it fixed. When I picked up my car, their salesnerd told me to watch my *left* headlight, for "once one headlight burns out, the other often follows in short order".

At first, I found that statement a little odd. But indeed, last Friday (14 days since the previous blowout, 8 days since repair), my left headlight burned out.

Was I just unlucky and the salesperson's tale is just superstition, or is this phenomenon an actual thing?

If so, what causes it? Uneven load/voltage issues?

For reference, my car is a 2013 Kia Rio UB.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: It's worth mentioning that car lights are almost always owner replaceable with very basic (or sometimes no) tools. Doing it yourself is a money saver.

Comment: Not necessarily true. Or - theoretically. Try replacing headlights on a Smart Coupe - you wil lbe surprised how ***** complex that thingy is. Without training you end up taking the front apart.

Comment: Agree with @TomTom. On VWs from 2003-2011 (my experience) you can do the whole thing w/o tools and it can take an hour to get the stupid bulb to lock in. Or, you can jack it up, take the tire off, take the fender liner off then replace the bulb in about a minute, replace the fender liner and replace the tire. I can do the extra work in about 30 minutes at home and it's worth it for the lower stress level and ease of each step, even though it's many more steps.

Comment: So dependent on the vehicle, my car it is an easy job one side and hard the other but only if you have small hands... which I don't... but I can still manage...

Comment: @GdD: these days there are plenty of cars where replacing the headlights is a major ordeal, unfortunately. My Mazda 6 required removing the whole front bumper to be able to replace the lights.

Comment: I'm not saying that it's easy to do on all cars @Various, there are of course exceptions and it would make good sense for an owner to explore the option.

Comment: Even on my '88 Pontiac 6000 and my '91 Olds Cutlass Supreme, it wasn't an easy task to replace the headlights.  It's wasn't super hard, but not easy.  On the other hand, I replaced the headlights on a friends Mustang (unknown year) w/o tools in about 5 min.  It really depends on the vehicle.

Comment: In my experience, the right one tends to be the one to give out first. This is natural, with it being nearer the side of the road where it's darker, so it will have the most work to do. That is also why the other one will give out soon after, as it will then have twice as much darkness to dispel all by itself. Also, although I fully stand by my opening sentence, please don't put too much belief in the rest of my post!

Comment: No, in a bright environment light striking the bulb will make it hotter, decreasing its lifetime.

Comment: @KlaymenDK While your joke made me laugh, it doesn't really help answer the question, so I've converted it to a comment. Besides, will it be the other way around in countries that drive on the left? ;-)

Comment: @NickC obviously only on the northern hemisphere, unless you get bulbs where the filament is wound the other way round. Right?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No, the salesman was spot on. If you think about it, bulbs are designed to last about the same amount of time. If they are installed in pairs, then the secondary light which matches the first will most likely be on the road to death just as the first. This holds mostly true for higher output lights, like your headlights. Marker lights, being a much lower output, will not hold true to this.

It is (IMHO) a good idea to replace headlights in pairs. Not only due to them lasting about the same amount of time, but also because as they get older, they start to dim. If you replace one headlight, there will be a distinct difference (in most cases) between the two. I guess that may not be an issue for everybody, but I'm just anal like that. I like the headlights to be even so as not to cause weird lighting effects across my field of vision at night.

Comment: Also, if you replace the pair, you have the good used one as a spare, in case the next failure happens at a bad time. (Keep it in the car, not somewhere else, of course!)

Comment: `I'm just anal like that` uh?

Comment: @Federico https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anal_retentiveness

Comment: It should be good to point out that, especially because of the reasons Paulster2 pointed out, it's always good practice to change headlight bulbs *before* they fail. Every couple of years, as a preventive move, it will both provide much better light output and will practically eliminate any sudden failures (of course, a new bulb can blow any time but in actual practice, when replaced relatively regularly, sudden failures are very rare, provided you use decent quality bulbs in the first place).

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I've noticed in older cars that when one blinker light burns out the other blinks faster and is brighter.  Could the wiring send extra voltage to one headlight while the other isn't pulling any amperage causing the light to become brighter and burn out more quickly as well?

Comment: @BillK That sounds like a decent separate question. I encourage you to post it as such.

Comment: One would expect bulb lifetimes to follow a roughly normal distribution. Is the standard deviation really _so_ low that it's reasonable to expect a second failure close to the first one? If the lifetime of bulbs was _that_ predictable and tightly correlated, wouldn't they replace them proactively when servicing the car?

Comment: @DavidRicherby FWIW I replaced the 2nd low beam in my 06 Buick within about a year of the first, and 1st replacements for about 60-80% of my assorted indicator lights occurred over about 2 years.  Round 2 of replacements for them felt more or less random, but probably just because the 4-6(?) year window from the 1st time was spread out to 8-12(?) even ignoring the more extreme outliers.

Comment: @DanNeely I can easily believe that "within about a year" is an effect of the distribution of bulb lifetimes, yes. But the idea that one should watch out for an imminent second failure seems to be assuming that the distribution is much more concentrated than seems likely.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I took it as just a "well you'll probably be replacing the second one soon, might as well do it now" type bit of precautionary advice.  If you're not bothered by differential brightness (I never noticed it) unless bad weather's coming up (ie winter and you don't have a heated garage) or you need to take it to the shop to be done I wouldn't bother.

Answer (score 7):

Lightbulb failure is a random event, which is not pre-set to happen after X hours of service or before a certain date. It is provoked by stress from vibration, repeated heating up and cooling down and voltage spikes above nominal voltage.

Having said that, lightbulbs have a predictable ageing process where their filament gradually thins out via evaporation. Thus a pair of lightbulbs from the same production batch will have quite close lifetimes, and since headlights are always switched on and off together, they tend to die within a small period of time.

I replace my headlight bulbs myself, but I tend to replace them in pairs nevertheless. The small amount of service time the second lightbulb still has is not worth the hassle of having to repeat the procedure a few weeks (months at best) down the road.

Answer (score 4):

In contrast to the other contributors I have never replaced both headlights at the same time. I am 64 years old and have been replacing my own lights since I had my first car. You will sometimes get a year or more of service out of the other headlight after you replace it's mate. Headlights, like any other lightbulb have a high degree of quality and durability difference even from the same manufacturer. However, if you're already paying someone to replace your headlights, I agree, it would make more sense to have them replace both. As always, your mileage may vary.

Comment: Agreed, but always carry a couple as spares. They are designed to blow, but as with everything there may be variance and all we can do is consider probabilities.

Comment: If you don't replace lightbulbs in pairs, how do you compare their service life? Also, if you don't buy them in pairs as well, they ought to have bigger variation due to variations in production process.